# How to "#define" this variable?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I have one integer value in 0x102 address and i need to create `#define ABC ...` macro.
ABC is variable or something (with access to 0x102 cell).
It must be possible to do operations like this  :

```
ABC = 666;  
int x = ABC*2 + 4;  
int *p = &ABC;
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: How do you *know* it will be at address `0x102`?

Comment: @ArjunShankar maybe he's using an embedded system?

Comment: btw how'bout `#define ABC ABC`?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your object is 16-bit (address 0x102 is 2-bytes aligned):

```
#define ABC  (*(volatile uint16_t *) 0x102)
```

Comment: I like your parentheses and `volatile` better than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
#define ABC *((int*)0x102)

int main() {
  ABC = -1;
  return 0;
}
```

It set an `int*` and then deferences it all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the address as a constant, you can write:

```
#define ABC (*(int *)0x102)
```

If you have a variable in that address (with a name such as `my_variable`):

What you want is what C++ calls references. In C, it doesn't exist. However, you could, as you guessed, use a macro for it.

If this variable is in the same scope as `ABC`, all you need is:

```
#define ABC my_variable
```

If you have a pointer to this variable (for example as a function argument), you can write something like this:

```
#define ABC (*that_argument)
```

Answer (score 0):

As compile time the compiler replaces the #defined variable with the actual value.

So, If you `#define ABC`

1) `ABC = 666;`
   You wont be able to perform this operation.

2) `int x = ABC*2 + 4;`
You will be able to perfrom this operation

3) `int *p = &ABC;`
   You wont be able to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding compile time macros. You can add `ABC=(*(int*)0x102)`it in Preprocessor field in project settings if you are using IDE. Or else if you are using CLI compiler, for example `gcc` you can compile the program as below.

```
gcc prog.c -DABC=(*(int*)0x102)
```

Or you can define it directly in the program also like below

```
#define ABC (*(int *)0x102)

int main()
{
    ABC = 666;  
    int x = ABC*2 + 4;  
    int *p = &ABC;  
    return 0;
}
```